# Can I assume that an empty user agent will always be a robot?

Tags: ddos, websites, bot

I want to prevent robots flooding my website and I'm thinking about a ban in these cases...

Can I assume that an empty user agent will always be a robot?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you consider a robot? If you want to ban anything but common browsers then blocking an empty user-agent might help you  a bit. But this will only help against a few non-browsers, most HTTP clients actually set some User-Agent and often they set it to something which looks like a browser in order to bypass simple restrictions.

Comment: I consider a "not human" :)

Comment: The User-Agent header, like any other HTTP header is under complete control of the client, so can be spoofed in many ways. Proxies may also "sanitize" it. So your assumption does not work and even if it does many other robots will come to your site with a non empty User-Agent header.

Comment: I know. But I was thinking....if someone make a fast try....like a curl in a terminal....and receive a block message. This guy doesnt know why Im blocking him. And it will be the first alert :) like "I know you are not doing something good here and Im watching you"

Comment: If an empty UA is always some code and never a human, I can ban him for some hours extending the second attempt to find out why he was banned

Comment: @KarlZillner: if *"someone make a fast try...like  curl in a termal"*  he will have a `User-Agent` header since tools like curl usually send such a header by default. Also, how *"someone make a fast try"* is usually considered a human which is in direct contrast to what you said you want to block, i.e. *"not human"*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean common browser users.

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to direct your efforts towards protecting against a DOS which might not conform to *your* predefined characteristics?

Answer (score 4):

Almost always, but not always. It could be a user behind a misconfigured proxy, or a browser extension, or (more likely) someone using telnet/netcat:

```
netcat server 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
<enter>
<enter>
```

And done.

You can ban users without `User-Agent` set, but it's dead easy to set one. `curl`, `wget`, `aria2`, `python` and almost every single command/library/framework out there will have an option to override the User-Agent string.

You'd better implement rate-limiting on sensible pages, captchas when the limit is reached, and ban after a number of captcha misses.

Comment: Yes...Its not the only rule, but I think if first access from a user is without user agent....hes just trying to use some curl thing.

Comment: `curl` have a defined user-agent string. It's something like `User-Agent: curl/7.12.3`

Comment: I've already set a rate limit. I'm just trying to improve my security

Comment: Yes....I search for some words in UA and ban them....like sqlmap, curl, downloader, trojan and anothers....

Comment: I voted this answer up, but I think that the “almost always” statement at the beginning should be removed. If a bot tries to access a website for some reason, its creator most likely specified a user-agent for it. Furthermore most programs you mentioned have default user agents, like the request lib in python.